# Is it possible to genereate more than 64 DCT basis functions?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

Is it possible to generate , let's say 512 DCT basis functions instead of the standard 64? If yes then how? Since for 64, the 4 'for' loops run for the range of 8 (when we try to generate the basis function from the DCT transform formula), so now for 512, how many times will I have to run each 'for' loop to correctly generate the basis functions? How can I validate whether the generated basis functions are correct or not? I am working on python.

Comment: You don't seem to master that theory. The DCT is periodic and there's nothing more to compute.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible. You just have to change the range on which you are running.
Now, 512 is not a square number, so you have to have two different values for ranging over the horizontal and vertical direction (say, 16 and 32, since 16*32 = 256)

You can take the code here and modify it according to your needs: https://github.com/chalmersgit/Discrete-Cosine-Transform

Comment: The code from GitHub link is a great support for me. Thank you for sharing. But, I have a question, in the case of dct basis functions we generate, there the (0, 0)th function is flat and from the output of the code I see it is complete black. That means a constant line in the 4th quadrant of the graph. Am I correct? 
If yes, next think is won't it suppose to be constant line in 1st quadrant? Or anyone could be possible?